# Correct use of tf.while_loop when variables are created inside body

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using a while_loop in Tensorflow in order to iterate over a tensor and extracting specific slices over a given dimension. For each step, I need to use a decoder RNN to generate a sequence of output symbols. I'm using the code provided in *tf.contrib.seq2seq*, in particular, [tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/dynamic_decode). The code looks similar to the following:

```
def decoder_condition(i, data, source_seq_len, ta_outputs):
    return tf.less(i, max_loop_len)

def decode_body(i, data, source_seq_len, ta_outputs):
    curr_data = data[:, i, :]
    curr_source_seq_len = source_seq_len[:, i, :]
    attention_mechanism = tf.contrib.seq2seq.LuongAttention(
        2 * self.opt["encoder_rnn_h_size"],
        curr_data,
        memory_sequence_length=curr_source_seq_len
    )
    cell = GRUCell(num_units)
    cell = AttentionWrapper(cell, attention_mechanism)
    # ... other code that initialises all the variables required
    # for the RNN decoder
    outputs = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(
        decoder,
        maximum_iterations=self.opt["max_sys_seq_len"],
        swap_memory=True
    )
    with tf.control_dependencies([outputs)]:
        ta_outputs = ta_outputs.write(i, outputs)

    return i+1, data, ta_outputs

 loop_index = tf.constant(0)
 gen_outputs = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
 outputs = tf.while_loop(
      decoder_condition,
      decoder_body,
      loop_vars=[
          loop_index,
          data,
          data_source_len,
          ta_outputs
      ],
      swap_memory=True,
      back_prop=True, 
      parallel_iterations=1
)
```

So as you can see, I create different objects which depend specifically on the input at the current step *i*. I'm using `tf.AUTO_REUSE` in my current variable scope in such a way that the variables are reused even if I'm creating different objects. Unfortunately, my decoder seems that it's not properly training because it keeps generating incorrect values. I've already checked the input data to the decoder RNN and everything is correct. I suspect that there is something that I'm not doing properly in terms of how TensorFlow manages the TensorArray and while_loop.

So my main questions are:

1. Is TensorFlow correctly propagating the gradients for each variable that it's created inside the while loop?
2. Is it possible to create object inside the while loop that are dependent on specific slices of a Tensor obtained using the loop index?
3. Does the *backprop* parameter guarantee that the gradients are propagated during training? Should it be set to False during inference?
4. In general, are there any sanity check that I can use to spot possible errors in my implementation?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
Not sure why but seems that there is an open issue about this which is related to the possibility to invoke custom operations in a while loop as explained here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13616. Unfortunately, I don't know enough TensorFlow's internals to judge if it's completely related to this.

UPDATE 2: 
I solved using PyTorch :)

Comment: Your decoder condition uses a variable (max_loop_len) that it's not given as an input? Are you using an optimizer?

Comment: `self.opt` contains all the parameters of my model that are specified as member of a class that incapsulate the code above. Sure, I'm using ADAM with a Cross Entropy loss function for seq2seq models (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/sequence_loss).

Answer (score 0):

(1) Yes

(2) Yes, just slice a tensor using the loop index

(3) No need to set backprop=False in ordinary use-cases

(4) The usual things you do with ML models (toy datasets, test parts separately, etc)

Re update 2, try using eager execution or tf.contrib.autograph; both should let you write the while loop in plain python.